# “give a shot” vs “have a go”

Tags: idioms

Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'give a shot' and 'have a go'? The definitions in Merriam-Webster Dictionary are:

- *give (something) a shot* : to try to do (something)
- *have a go* : to try to do something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference in meaning, but *give it a shot* would only be used in informal conversation among adults. If you were teaching a young child to do some task like tying their shoelaces, you would probably say "Now you have a go", not "Now you give it a shot."